# Получить значение свойства Polygon для отображения в балуне

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Как в балун получить какое-либо значение из Polygon.properties?

Answer (score 1):

Если речь идёт об балуне этого же полигона, то можно сделать это через пару set-get.

Например получить в балун содержимое хинта можно так:

```
myPolygon.properties.set('balloonContent',myPolygon.properties.get('hintContent'))
```

Comment: При открытии балуна получить свойства полигона и эти значения добавить в контент балуна. Вот в чем сложность возникла.

Comment: Какие именно свойства? Я показал, как получить свойство (properties) 'hintContent', которое было задано при создании полигона. Точно так же можно получить и остальные свойства. В чём именно проблема? Приведите конкретный пример, например на JSFiddle, и укажите, какое свойство получить не удаётся.